# git checkout master does not work after i created a branch....what can I do?

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-commit, git-status

I have created a file called basic and I have created a branch called new. After moving to the new branch, I want to switch to the master branch, hence i used git checkout master. Unfortunately, the terminal stated there is no master branch.

```
(base) Dun-Yan:basic ongdunyan$ git checkout master
error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

Here is the git status:

```
(base) Dun-Yan:basic ongdunyan$ git status
On branch new
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

I would appreciate if you all can help me, peace :)

Comment: Some tips: use `git branch` to list all your local branches or `git fetch && git branch -r` to list all remote branches to be sure that the base branch name was master at all. 2: to go back to previous branch you can always use `git checkout -`

Comment: I bet this is a fresh repo so no master yet exists. Did I win the bet?

Comment: ```git checkout -``` didnt work, instead

Comment: ```(base) Dun-Yan:basic ongdunyan$ git checkout -
error: pathspec '-' did not match any file(s) known to git```

Comment: Maybe it is called `main`, not `master`? Use `git branch` to list all your local branches or `git reflog` to show which old commits or branches were checked out

Answer (score 0):

You have to make at least one commit on `master` before you check out to a different branch, otherwise the branch HEAD will practically not exist and git cannot checkout back to "nowhere".

Answer (score 0):

This means that, yes indeed, there is no branch named `master`.  There's no requirement that any Git repository have any particular branch names—you can have a repository with *no* branch names at all—so that's not an *error*, unless of course you *want* it to be one.

Use `git branch` to list out all the existing branch names.  In a new, empty repository, this would print no names as there are no branches, but your `git status` output indicates that you do at least have one branch name, specifically `new`.

Use `git branch -r` to list out all the existing *remote-tracking* names.  That should make you ask: *wait, what's a remote-tracking name?*  (Especially since Git calls this a *remote-tracking branch name:* I drop the word *branch* because these names aren't actually *branch* names at all.)  A remote-tracking name is the way your Git remembers some *other* repository's branch names.

The key insight here is that your branch names are *yours*.  They are not anyone else's branches.  Just as your name might be Sue, or Rajeesh, or Quentin, or whatever, that doesn't mean that *everyone* named Sue (or whatever your name may be) is *you*.  Your Git repository has *its own* branch names.  You may want yours to match up with someone else's, but that's just a desire on your part, not something Git *must* do.

When you have your Git—your Git software operating on your Git repository—talk to some other Git (software on another repository), the two Gits will confer, and your Git will be able to see their commits and their branches (to whatever extent they're willing to show them anyway).  Your Git will *get* their branches-and-commits when you run `git fetch`.  But your Git will turn their *branch names* into your *remote-tracking names*, so that if they have a branch named `fred`, you get a remote-tracking branch with some other name.

In order to have your Git talk to another Git, you will set your Git up with what Git calls a *remote*.  A remote is just a short name like `origin`: we have Git store a *URL* under this shorter name, and then we run:

```
git fetch origin
```

to direct our Git to look up the short name, `origin`, find the long URL (`ssh://git@github.com/some/path/to/repo.git` or `https://github.com/some/path/to/repo.git` or whatever), and connect there and see their branches and commits.

Having seen `origin`'s branch named `fred`, if your Git is directed to bring it over—that's the default—you will then find, in your repository, the *remote-tracking name* `origin/fred`.  This represents the *branch* name `fred` as seen on the *remote* named `origin`.

The `git branch -r` command lists out these remote-tracking names.  Using `git branch -a`, your Git will list out your branch names *and* your remote-tracking names, so that you will be able to see your `new` and—if it exists at this point—your `origin/fred`.  For whatever reason,<sup>1</sup> `git branch -r` prints this one as `origin/fred` and `git branch -a` prints it as `remotes/origin/fred`.

Now, you might want your Git to *create a new branch name*, and you can do that.  You should, however, first read up on how commits and branch names actually work.  Git uses the names only<sup>2</sup> to find *commits:* it's really the commits and their hash IDs (or "object IDs", to be formal) that matter.

---

<sup>1</sup>This is just plain inconsistent.  Both forms work: you can write either `origin/fred` or `remotes/origin/fred`, if you like.  But there's no solid reason for this difference in output format.  The actual full name `origin/fred` is `refs/remotes/origin/fred`, and if one is going to go to the effort to insert the `remotes/` part, why not go all the way and put in the unambiguous `refs/remotes/origin/fred` version?  But that's all just an aside.

<sup>2</sup>Well, *mainly* is more accurate than *only*, since branch names also participate in key-value lookups for `branch.*` settings in your configuration.